# Regex must start with specific number, must contain 2 hyphens and must end with 4 digit numbers

Tags: c#, regex, string, numbers, digits

I am a bit puzzled on how to achieve this after trying so many times.
It needs to start with 2 numbers, first number must be 9, then hyphen, then A-Za-z, then dot, then A-Za-z, then hyphen, and end must have 4 digits.

Simple terms for those who don't understand the question:
"9<1 digit here>-<sometext.sometext>-<4digits>"

Problem starts with the character dot in the middle of the string.
Here is my regex:

```
^([9])([a-zA-Z0-9]*-*\.){2}[a-zA-Z0-9]\d{4}$
```

Example input:

- 90-Amir.h-8394
- 91-Hamzah.K-4752

Tried figuring out where to put the syntax for the Regex to detect the character dot. But it is not working.

Comment: What is the rule here? You described a syntax that should not support any dot.

Comment: can the dot be anywhere between the first 2 digits and the last 4? For example, is "92.5348" a valid string ?

Comment: @AoooR the dot can be anywhere

Comment: Does it _have to be_ Regex? You could probably code these rules faster than find a regex for all of them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I fixed my regex syntax, it should be able to contain dot

Comment: @Fildor must be a regex, it is a UI Builder Form, which I can put regex

Comment: @AmirHamzah Ok so `9[0-9]\.[0-9]{4}` matches all your specifications I think

Comment: Do the mandatory hyphens need to be after the first 2 digits and before the last 4 ?

Comment: @AoooR There are no mandatory hyphens in that regex, are they?

Comment: @Fildor hyphens needs to be after the first 2 digits and before the last 4, correct

Comment: @AoooR thanks, but that is just a partial solution, without the hyphens

Comment: @AmirHamzah Sorry I didn't see it before the post was edited, I try to correct my regex and I come back

Comment: You still have not explained anywhere in the question where the dots are expected, where they must be or where they can be. Look how  many comments you have generated by omitting that important bit.

Comment: So, it is safe to say the regex should check for something with this "template": "9<digit>-<sometext>-<4digits>" right?

Comment: @AmirHamzah Maybe it is not optimized because this regex is very long, but I have `9[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*\-[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\-[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9]{4}` which means `9<number><any string>-<any string>.<any string>-<any string><4digits>` is this what you need ?

Comment: @Fildor like this 9<1 digit here>-<sometext.sometext>-<4digits>

Comment: I have also included 2 input string

Comment: "9<1 digit here>-<sometext.sometext>-<4digits>" can be translated almost verbatim to a regex: @"9\d-\w+\.\w+-\d{4}"

Comment: Your pattern description tells me `^9\d-[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+-\d{4}$` will do. See https://regex101.com/r/4x3Oro/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `9<1 digit here>-<sometext.sometext>-<4digits>` as:

```
^9[0-9]-[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+-[0-9]{4}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `9[0-9]` Match `9` and a digit 0-9
- `-` Match `=`
- `[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+` Match 1+ chars A-Za-z then `.` and again 1+ chars A-Za-z
- `-[0-9]{4}` Match `-` and 4 digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uFZbBv/1).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [`^9[0-9]-.*\..*-[0-9]{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/d9fhks/1)

First, it sets the position at the start of the line with `^`
Then it checks if there is a `9` followed by any single number `[0-9]` and a hyphen `-`

After that, it checks for random characters until the next hyphen `-` and makes sure the last part is any random 4 digit number `[0-9]{4}`

To finish, it's alway good to make sure the end of the line is reached with `$`

**Edit 1**:
To make sure the text is formatted like `aaaa.bbbb`, one can simply use `.*\..*`

I added this change to the regex above

Comment: What about the "dot" that seems to be required within the middle part ("sometext.sometext")?

Comment: you can replace `[0-9]` by `\d` and `{1}` is useless

Comment: @KlausGütter Unfortunately, these specifications weren't included when I took a look at the question. I updated my answer as soon as i saw it.

Comment: @AoooR yes, thats right. But I think its a bit easier to understand this way.

Comment: @noah Do not use `{1}`, it confuses people that start to believe it always makes the regex match a single occurrence of a char. A char is always tried once by default. Do you really think it is easier to understand `s{1}l{1}e{1}e{1}p{1}` than `sleep` regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, thats a good point. But I do think that, at least for beginners, `[0-9]` is easier to understand than `\d`